# Two way Anova - 2 not defined because of singularies error

Tags: anova

I am new to statistics and have read that this might be attributed to multicollinear varibles from ["2 not defined because of singularities"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/341105/2-not-defined-because-of-singularities) and may be fixed with a dummy variable trap. Could it be because there are too few observations in those 2 categories?

[image]

Would this also work for the two way anova,is the problem the same?If so can some provide a step by step procedure for me; or a video link on how to fix it?

Here is plot of means if it helps as EDA

[image]

Comment: What does table(gravidity, method.delivery) look like?

Comment: @mdewey I added a graph of the plot of means if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph now added clearly show that there are no observations in two of the cells (two of the breech cells) so the interaction cannot include them. This is probably nothing to worry about although much depends on the scientific question. One might want to know why only second and subsequent babies are breech but I know nothing of obstetrics.

Comment: Good point! There was only 1 observation for breech, guess I will just remove it